# Postman receiving cookie but my browser isn't receiving it when I try

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flask, cookies, axios

I am making a website with flask and react. The user inputs an email and password on a form, axios.post to the backend, backend checks if email and password is correct with database, if so, backend returns a cookie. In postman the cookie is set, not in my browser. Apparently the frontend is receiving nothing from the backend in my browser, because it doesnt even print the console.log that I put in the axios.post. In postman the cookie is set, not in my browser

Axios post:

```
  const handleLogin = function(){
    axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/login", {email:email, password:password}, {withCredentials:true, headers : {'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data'}}).then(response => {

      if(response.data["message"] == "Logado com sucesso"){
        history.push('/');
      }

    }).catch(error => {alert(error.response.data); console.error("Error occurred in login request:", error);});
```

flask return:

```
if(check_password_hash(data[19],password)):
            resposta = make_response(jsonify({"message": "Logado com sucesso"}))
            resposta.set_cookie('id', str(data[0]), httponly=True, samesite='None')
            return resposta
```

> Apparently the frontend is receiving nothing from the backend in my browser, because it doesnt even print the console.log that I put in the axios.post. I set the CORS to support credentials and axios.post withCredentials:true.

Comment: shouldn't you be using ```'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'```

Comment: form-data does about the same, the problem isnt the data that the frontend is sending, it's what the frontend is receiving, I just don't know what the problem is

Comment: by **doesnt even print the console.log** you mean the console.log you put inside he catch block?

Comment: I'm not a flask expert, but since Postman works and frontend doesn't, it makes me think of CORS error.
Can you try to enable CORS * on your backend just to see if it solves (I know it's not ideal, but at least we can understand if the error is there or not)

Comment: I put one console.log in the then block and another in the catch block, it prints neither

Comment: CORS is enabled, CORS(app, supports_credentials=True, origins='*') this is in the backend